# Where am I going wrong in trying to import a class?

Tags: java, import, path, package

Here's the code for the source file:

```
package moa4;
public class Book {
    ....
}
```

And for the destination file:

```
import moa4.Book;

public class Library {
    ...
}
```

The source and the destination are both saved in the same directory with the address:
C:\Users\\java\M\moa4

I'm getting the following error: package moa4 does not exist

Comment: you need to have M in your classpath I believe. I forget exactly how java works. I think it is `javac -cp C:\Users\java\M blahblahblah.java`.
If you can, try to use a build framework like maven or an IDE like eclipse.

Comment: If `Library` is not part of the `moa4` package, it should not be in the `moa4` folder.

Comment: You shouldn't need to import the package, if the folder is the same. The package is the "file system equivalent" to a directory, everything inside the same package is visible for every class inside it.

Comment: If `Library` _is_ supposed to be part of the `moa4` package, add `package moa4;` and take out the `import`.

Comment: It says "cannot access Book" now.

Comment: Now in fact there is a second problem, the Library class has no package! :) Setting the package to moa4 should be sufficient.

Comment: Try compiling `moa4/*.java` from the parent folder.

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Here's the latest update:
I've removed the import command in Library.java and instead have a package moa4 statement in both the Library and the Book file. Both the programs are stored in the same file titled moa4.
Now I get "error:cannot find symbol
symbol: class Book
location: class Library"

Also, I had the impression that all I had to do to create a package was to ensure all source files comprising the package lie in the same folder (named after the package) with a package <packageName>; statement right at the top. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Ok, Resolved. I started working on the Eclipse IDE. Worked with the modified code. Still don't have the hang of creating packages without the IDE. So I guess that's where the mistake lay.

Answer (score 0):

You asked `Library` to import a package `moa4.Book` but you defined no such package. Instead, you defined a *type* `Book` inside package `moa4`, and that is not consistent with your `import` directive.

You could either import the package, or make that an `import static` of the class, but since `Book` and `Library` are both in the same package you don't need the `import` directive at all.

As mentioned, `C:/Users/java/M` needs to be in your classpath ("`-cp`" option).